# Intellij idea compile

Tags: java, intellij-idea

when I try to run my code, it says

```
D:\collinear\.idea\workspace.xml
Failed to load project configuration: cannot parse file D:\collinear\.idea\workspace.xml: Unexpected end tag: expected </todo-panel>
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [82,11]
```

Could any one help with this?

The original file code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ChangeListManager">
    <list default="true" id="de3c797f-950b-4f17-a955-daf1b2a2e70a" name="Changes" comment="" />
    <option name="SHOW_DIALOG" value="false" />
    <option name="HIGHLIGHT_CONFLICTS" value="true" />
    <option name="HIGHLIGHT_NON_ACTIVE_CHANGELIST" value="false" />
    <option name="LAST_RESOLUTION" value="IGNORE" />
  </component>
  <component name="ProjectId" id="2CSYuDBFUzu27f0DeiBxNrUgEMo" />
  <component name="ProjectViewState">
    <option name="abbreviatePackageNames" value="true" />
    <option name="autoscrollFromSource" value="true" />
    <option name="autoscrollToSource" value="true" />
    <option name="hideEmptyMiddlePackages" value="true" />
    <option name="showExcludedFiles" value="false" />
    <option name="showModules" value="false" />
    <option name="sortByType" value="true" />
  </component>
  <component name="PropertiesComponent"><![CDATA[{
  "keyToString": {
    "RunOnceActivity.OpenProjectViewOnStart": "true",
    "RunOnceActivity.ShowReadmeOnStart": "true"
  }
}]]></component>
  <component name="SpellCheckerSettings" RuntimeDictionaries="0" Folders="0" CustomDictionaries="0" DefaultDictionary="project-level" UseSingleDictionary="true" transferred="true" />
</project>
```

This is the code
Computer vision involves analyzing patterns in visual images and reconstructing the real-world objects that produced them. The process is often broken up into two phases: feature detection and pattern recognition. Feature detection involves selecting important features of the image; pattern recognition involves discovering patterns in the features. We will investigate a particularly clean pattern recognition problem involving points and line segments. This kind of pattern recognition arises in many other applications such as statistical data analysis.

Comment: Can you post the file around where it mentions it in the error?

Comment: Sure, I added them

Comment: You posted this error: `cannot parse file D:\collinear\.idea\workspace.xml: Unexpected end tag: expected </todo-panel>` – The error doesn't mention anything about Java code. Have you looked at workspace.xml? Can you post that file here?

Comment: I edited, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I don't see anyway that file can cause the error you say it does. I suggest closing IntelliJ, deleting the .idea folder, then opening the project again in IntelliJ.

Comment: It doesn't work I tried it before

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project for investigation?